# Passing event args from javascript to code-behind while using ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to trigger a postback from *java-script* and also pass event args. I'm able to trigger the postback **but not able to pass event args.

The below function does not work. It does not like the `args` parameter in `ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function TriggerServerSideClick(args) {
  //btnDummy is a asp.net server-side button control            
  <%=ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnDummy, args , true)%>

  //tried this ->  <%= 'ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference
  //      (btnDummy,' + args + ', true)' %> , 
  //      but i guess i am definitely missing something.
}

</script>
```

What am I missing here ?

I know that the following works

```
 __doPostBack('btnDummy', args);
```

but want to stay away from `__doPostBack` as that could change eventually and try the `ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference` instead.

Thanks for your time.

@Brian: Thanks a lot for following up. I tried your placeholder approach but I am getting a javascript error. (**Message: Expected ';'**)
Here is the viewsource snippet:

```
var postbackUrl = '__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$btnDummy','{0}')';

   function TriggerServerSideClick(args) {

      var url = String.format(postbackUrl, args);
      eval(url);
   }
```

Comment: It's missing a semi-colon at the end, inside the postbackUrl string.  When evaluated, there is no ending ;.

Comment: Thanks again for your persistence. That did not work, tried debugging with firebug, chrome dev tools as well. Not sure what is missing ? snippet: var postbackUrl = '__doPostBack('btnDummy','{0}');';

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var postbackUrl = '<%=ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnDummy, "{0}", true)%>';

function TriggerServerSideClick(args) {
   var url = String.format(postbackUrl, args);
   eval(url);
}
```

Put a placeholder where the argument should be, then use a client-side method to replace the placeholder (client-side String.format method) and use that to postback.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks, like I said,  I do not want to explicitly call __doPostBack(...) method in favor of ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference.

Comment: Thanks. Ok the problem is not the choice of ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference overload [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getpostbackeventreference.aspx)                                                          The issue is sending arguments variable, not a hard-coded string  such as "My Argument". I am trying to send a string representation of json as arguments.                                               E.g.: <%= Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(new PostBackOptions(btnDummy, jsonStrArgs)) %>

Comment: Updated above - no direct client/server mixing and matching, but you can use a workaround to do it.

Comment: Yes, inside the postback url string, there is no ending ;, change to: var postbackUrl = '<%=ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnDummy, "{0}", true)%>;';

Comment: Thanks again for your persistence. That did not work, tried debugging with firebug, chrome dev tools as well. Not sure what is missing ? snippet: var postbackUrl = '__doPostBack('btnDummy','{0}');';

Comment: It's erroring when the eval() is called, which is why I mentioned the ; where i put it... is it the same error?

Comment: Yes it still says expected ;. The error occurs before the eval() call. The line below is the cause of error                                var postbackUrl = '<%=ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnDummy, "{0}", true)%>;'; // Please note that I added the semi-colon as per ur suggestion. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from Brian Mains sent me in the right direction when I was working on this issue just now. The only difference being, that I didn't use the client-side string.Format - I used the mainstream JavaScript string.replace:

```
//js
args = someComplicatedDynamicStuff();
myPostback = <%= Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "args")
                     .Replace("'", "\\'") %>; // server-side replace to 
                                              // inject string delimiters
eval(myPostback.replace('args',args));
```